# Convert VS dll 32 bit to 64 bit causes unresolved external symbol

Tags: windows, visual-studio, fortran, intel-fortran, dllexport

I wrote a dll in Fortran 90 with Visual Studio 2010 and built for 32bit platforms.
When I call this library from a main program built for 32bit platform it works.
If I built the same dll for 64bit and call it from a main program for 64.bit platform I find the following error:

```
Error   1    error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol SELECT referenced in function MAIN__
```

What is wrong?

This is the called subroutine.
`SELECT` is the called subroutine.

```
SUBROUTINE SELECT( i )
!DEC$ ATTRIBUTES DLLEXPORT, STDCALL :: SELECT
!DEC$ ATTRIBUTES ALIAS: '_SELECT@4' :: SELECT
!DEC$ ATTRIBUTES REFERENCE :: i
    integer*4 :: i
END SUBROUTINE SELECT
```

Comment: Wrong alias, identifiers are not decorated in 64-bit code.  So the linker goes looking for SELECT instead of _SELECT@4, just like the linker error message says.

Comment: Welcome, I suggest taking the [tour]. Please use tag [tag:fortran] for Fortran questions. Fortran 90 is just one very old version of the standard.

Answer (score 1):

In a 32bit library symbols are decorated with additional characters. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/debug/decorated-symbol-names The 4 in @4 specifies that there are 4 bytes on the stack used for function parameters.That used for stack cleanup in this particular calling convention (stdcall).

This is not used in 64 bit so

```
 !DEC$ ATTRIBUTES ALIAS: '_SELECT@4'
```

creates a wrong name. You need just

```
 !DEC$ ATTRIBUTES ALIAS: 'SELECT'
```

because the error message says that this symbol is expected.

The

```
!DEC$ ATTRIBUTES DLLEXPORT, STDCALL :: SELECT
```

is ignored in 64 bit.